# How do I obtain permission to publish a google script as a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I attempt to deploy my Google Apps Script as a web app, I get a message saying "You do not have permission to perform that action." It would be great if the message had a link to how to resolve that issue.
I've looked and have undoubtedly missed something both important and well-hidden :)
So, how do I obtain permission?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you on a G Suite domain?  You may need to get this from your administrator.

Comment: Make sure you are publishing from the owner of the script.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you first need to decide whose authorization the app should run with. As mentioned in [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions),

> The permissions for a web app differ depending on whether you choose to execute the app as the owner of the script or as the active user who is accessing the web app.
>
> If you choose for the script to execute as you, then the script will always execute under your identity, that is, the identity of the owner of the script. This will be the case regardless of which user is accessing the web app.
>
> If you choose for the script to execute as the user who accesses the web app, then the script will execute under the identity of the active user who is accessing your script.

To confirm whose authorization will it be, select whose authorization the app should run with under the **Execute the app as**. Please check steps given in [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

For more information, you may want to visit [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and also [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization).